# Error in building libcamera - Debian 'Bullseye'

Tags: camera, linux, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, libcamera

Very new to Raspberry Pi & Linux programming, have only been tinkering with it for the past month, so assume I know nothing.

Context: I am using a custom 'lite' image from the Cluster Hat website on a pizero intended to be slotted into the HAT. The intent is to have 4 pizero's, each hooked up to a camera, and simultaneously capture 4 pictures of the same object, so it's important a camera is hooked up to each PiZero. In any case, the image provided was fairly out of date, and after updating everything, I attempted to run the `libcamera-hello` command and ran into this error:

```csh
~ $ libcamera-hello --qt-preview
Preview window unavailable
[3:50:05.192541323] [19229]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:293 libcamera v0.0.0+3866-0c55e522
[3:50:05.256764631] [19230]  INFO RPI raspberrypi.cpp:1374 Registered camera /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx477@1a to Unicam device /dev/media3 and ISP device /dev/media0
[3:50:05.258008024] [19229]  INFO Camera camera.cpp:1035 configuring streams: (0) 2028x1520-YUV420
[3:50:05.258793654] [19230]  INFO RPI raspberrypi.cpp:761 Sensor: /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx477@1a - Selected sensor format: 2028x1520-SBGGR12_1X12 - Selected unicam format: 2028x1520-pBCC
[3:50:05.820926093] [19230] ERROR V4L2 v4l2_videodevice.cpp:1890 /dev/video14[15:cap]: Failed to start streaming: No such file or directory
ERROR: *** failed to start camera ***
```

I tried editing the boot file as well:

```
#Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver
dtoverlay=imx477     #this line was added by me
gpu_mem=256          #so was this line
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d,cma-512
max_framebuffers=2
```

I again tried several variations of the command all of them had this result. After some searching around, some people mentioned an outdated or improper library, so I set about trying to re-build the `libcamera` library. So, here are the commands I used to do so, [following the instructions provided here](https://libcamera.org/getting-started.html):

```
~ $ git clone https://git.libcamera.org/libcamera/libcamera.git
~ $ sudo apt install meson ninja-build pkg-config
~ $ sudo apt install g++
~ $ sudo apt install clang
~ $ sudo apt install -C build install
~ $ sudo apt install libyaml-dev python3-yaml python3-ply python3-jinja2
~ $ sudo apt install libssl-dev openssl libdw-dev libunwind-dev libudev-dev
~ $ sudo apt install libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev
~ $ sudo apt install libdrm-dev libjpeg libsdl2-dev

~ $ cd libcamera
~/libcamera $ meson build
~/libcamera $ ninja -C build install
```

It is worth noting the first time I ran that last command, I did *not* have have `clang` installed or `g++` (so I thought), and it stalled on `[53/149]` for about 5 minutes. I cancelled it, and installed both `g++` and `clang` thinking this was the reason for it locking up. `g++` showed up as being already installed. Now, when I run that last command, it stalls immediately:

```
$ ninja -C build install
ninja: Entering directory 'build'
[0/149] Compiling C++ object src/libca...ibcamera.so.0.0.0.p/bayer_format.cpp.o
```

And now when I run `libcamera-hello` I am hit with `ERROR: *** no cameras available ***`
Most issues until now I was able to solve in an afternoon of googling, but this one is pretty out of my depth. Thank you for your time reading, and any help is appreciated :)

---UPDATE:---

First of all, fixed the "hang" in the build process by running ninja as `ninja -C build install -j1` which restricts the number of parallel processes to 1 (i.e., one line at a time) ninja apparently has a habit of using system resources a lot - [see here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/56.0.2924.56/docs/ninja_build.md) It slows the build to slightly more of a crawl, but at least it actually finishes this way instead of completely hanging up the system. Reminder I am running this on a Pi Zero W, so system resources are quite sparse - on a RPi 2/3/etc. or even a Pi Zero 2 you could probably get away with `-j2` or even higher.

This surfaced a new issue with `meson` which I fixed by installing meson/pip as root. this does require both `meson build` and `ninja -C build install -j1` to be run as `sudo`

So, the library builds but I am *still* stuck with `ERROR: *** no cameras available ***` when I run `libcamera-hello`

Comment: In config.txt. Add this camera_auto_detect=0

Comment: @toyotaSupra Thank you for the response. I tried adding `camera_auto_detect=0` when I got in this morning and unfortunately, there was no change after a reboot.

Comment: But first. I refreshed new image. Then I installed OpenCV. Then after, it was worked. Then I tried libcamera- hello.. Everything is working fine.. But before that, I added config.txt.

Comment: @toyotaSupra Refreshing the image is a worst-case scenario. I mentioned I was using a custom bullseye image anyway, and if this issue is baked into said image from the beginning, then it's a moot point and I'd rather find a workaround.

I haven't tried OpenCV yet though. I will give that a go

Comment: picamera2 is already released.