# Best way to create Docker image to run on Raspberry Pi4/Debian12 Bookworm using libcamera

Tags: pi-4, docker, libcamera

What is the best way to build and run a Docker image on a Raspberry Pi 4B (4GB) so I can run the latest version of libcamera.  I have put together a Dockerfile based on the feedback from [Error in building libcamera - Debian 'Bullseye'](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/139326/error-in-building-libcamera-debian-bullseye)

```
FROM debian:bookworm-slim
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gcc libffi-dev python3-dev && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y meson ninja-build pkg-config
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y g++
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y clang
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libyaml-dev python3-yaml python3-ply python3-jinja2
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libssl-dev openssl libdw-dev libunwind-dev libudev-dev
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libdrm-dev libjpeg-dev libsdl2-dev

WORKDIR /app
RUN git clone https://git.libcamera.org/libcamera/libcamera.git
RUN cd libcamera

WORKDIR /app/libcamera
RUN meson build
RUN ninja -C build install -j4

CMD ["bash"]
```

To build and run I am using:

```
docker build -t test_video_image .
docker run --name test_video_container --rm --entrypoint="" -it test_video_image bash
```

The image builds on the Pi4 (takes a LONG time).  However when running the image, I am not able to run `libcamera-hello --list-cameras` etc...

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `apt-get update && apt-get install` why are you apt-get update before each and every apt-get install? and `rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` after  the first two installs? and installing `build-essential` twice - all these things add unnecessary time

Comment: `I am not able to run ...` what happens when you try?

Comment: at a guess though, you have not given access to the camera to the docker container

Comment: apt-get update && is an old bad habit...

when running: libcamera-hello
-bash: libcamera-hello: command not found

In regards to your guess it is not correct -- my question is being able to run libcamera-hello 

Docker privileges and access to the camera is another discussion not needed now.

Comment: your question states you can't run `libcamera-hello --list-cameras` ... why not? what happens when you try? Oh, wait, you answered that in your comment ... nevermind

Comment: OK, so you're building libcamera ... what does that have to do with the command you try to run? You're building a library, not an executable

Comment: what you may need to do is 1. add the raspberry pi repo, 2. install rpicam-apps ... of course, this won't be using this newly build library, because it will install the version that is applicable to the rpicam-apps ... which I believe is libcamera-0.1.1 - oh, that's the current version ...